# How do I resolve the error "No file system is defined for scheme: sourcecontrol" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control, rational-team-concert

I recently updated Eclipse, I have a project in RTC (Rational Team Concert).

When I open my workspace it says all my files are missing.

When I double click on a project I get: No file system is defined for scheme: sourcecontrol

Comment: Is RTC still working?  Sounds like it might have been disabled.  Is anything shown in the Error Log view?

Comment: Nope, if I got to my RTC view I get Errors on eveything e.g "Could not create the view: com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui.teamArtifactsNavigator"

Answer (score 2):

The kind of error message is typical of a faulty installation/update of RTC on top of an Eclipse Distribution:

```
Could not create the view: com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui.teamArtifactsNavigator
```

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/30407/rtc-2002-clinet-installation-problem-on-rsa-755) only offers one solution:

> I finally got it fixed by doing a fresh install of RSA 7.5.4 and installing RTC 2.0.0.2 client on top of it.

In your case, one way would be to make a new installation of your Eclipse Distribution, and try installing RTC on top of it, to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (RSA 8.5.5.1, RTC plugin 4.0.6) after adding another plugin.
I uninstalled the RTC plugin via IBM Installation Manager and reinstalled it.
After this I had to restart RSA with the `-clean` option once.
No need to reinstall RSA.